# What's the most unique sound you ever captured, before  processing or editing etc?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design, field-recording, recording

Hey guys I'd like to hear from everyone which of their sounds they ever recorded was their most unique? I'm asking specifically for sounds that have no processing or editing done to them so anything straight from the field.

Answer (score 2):

Was recording stuff in a narrow 12 story stairwell. Whenever I needed to adjust levels etc I would run up or down to where my gear was (5, 6, 7, 8 stories away). The reverb would swell as I would run towards it, going from wet to progressively dry. At the time I thought nothing of it, it wasn't even the sound I set out to record. But when I played back it was magic! I reprocess those samples regularly and has been used for so much material.

Answer (score 1):

Though not my absolutely best nor even most useful sound...frankly, not even close...but by all means my most unusual and funny sound, was something I recorded while being a music producer/sound engineer apprentice! The studio lies at a former school with marble absolutely everywhere in the stairways, so I filled one of the stairs with AKG CK1's, about four of them I think, recorded on a DAT, and emptied an entire humongous garbage-sack stuffed to the brim with aluminum cans once containing soda, beer and flavored water right down the stairs! Haha, it was one of the funniest sessions I've ever done! :-D

Comment: @Christian van Caine, I want that sound!

Comment: @Jay Jennings - Sure do-able! I'm gonna hit the sack now, but I'll get in touch tomorrow after work :-)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very unique (well as fart I guess it is cause I've never heard one like this) but it's one of the first things I recorded with my NTG-2 not intentionally, my brother just got near the mic while it was recording, but I really like this recording for some reason.

[soundcloud]stephensaldanha/weird-high-pitch-fart[/soundcloud]

Here's something fun, I challenged Nick Maxwell to design something with it and this is what he made:

[soundcloud]nickmaxwell/swirling-death-vortex[/soundcloud]

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on another SSD thread before but it's worth repeating -

Dual-hydrophone recording of a sunken wooden box filled with 30 live Maine lobsters crawling all over each other.

Take your worst insect-invasion nightmare and amplify it by 1000!

Comment: Would love to hear that. Reminded me of a recording Chris watson made from inside a carcass while it was being eaten by Vultures - amazing how proximity really makes recordings like that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this recording from inside a london post box. Lots of natural resonance.

[soundcloud]mark-durham/london-from-inside-a-post-box[/soundcloud]

Answer (score 0):

I'll all for putting mics where they shouldnt normally go! (erm..up to a point of course! lol)

I've put my handheld recorder into places like fridges and oven's before (VERY low heat!) and got some interesting sounds of their inner workings ;)

Oven
      [Oven](http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis/sets/oven) by [AndrewJohnLewis](http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis)

Fridge in here..
      [Random Ambience Recordings](http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis/sets/random-ambience-recordings) by [AndrewJohnLewis](http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis)